# How does the CSS selector work in this code? "class + element.class"

Tags: css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using Semantic UI React.
The code below makes the Popup element with the circular "i" trigger button appear inside the bounds of the button that precedes it, and looks like so:

[image]

CSS file:

```
  .pennai .builder-scene .algorithm-btn + i.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.1em;
  right: .1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

JS snippet:

```
        <Grid.Column key={algorithm._id}>
          <Button
            fluid
            inverted
            color="orange"
            size="large"
            active={getIsActive(algorithm)}
            onClick={() => setCurrentAlgorithm(algorithm)}
            className="algorithm-btn"
          >
            {formatAlgorithm(algorithm.name)}
            <div className="param-count">
              {`${Object.keys(algorithm.schema).length} parameters`}
            </div>
          </Button>
          <Popup
            on="click"
            position="right center"
            header={formatAlgorithm(algorithm.name)}
            content={
              <div className="content">
                <p>{algorithm.description}</p>
                {algorithm.url &&
                  <a href={algorithm.url} target="_blank"><strong>Read more here <Icon name="angle double right" /></strong></a>
                }
              </div>
            }
            trigger={
              <Icon
                inverted
                size="large"
                color="orange"
                name="info circle"
              />
            }
          />
        </Grid.Column>
```

My question is how does the CSS selector work for this? The Button includes `className="algorithm-btn"`, but my naive take on the CSS selector seems like it should be the Popup element that needs to be told to place itself relative to its ancestor, and thus it should receive the `.algorithm-btn` class?

Comment: It's targeting the icon, not the popup. You can learn more about selectors on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#Reference_table_of_selectors)

Comment: It's selecting the icon which is placed directly after the `.pennai .builder-scene .algorithm-btn` element.

Comment: Yes I see that it selects the icon. What I don't understand is why the class is assigned to the Button and not the Icon element, since it's the Icon element we're changing. Perhaps it's to keep things more consistent with the 'general  sibling combinator', for which it would make more sense to apply the class to the first sibling since it can match multiple other siblings?